# Number of 'hokage' words

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recursion

Let n be any natural number. Now define a 'hokage' word as a word consisting only of A,B, and C letters, such that no letter A is followed immediately by B and no letter B is followed immediately by A. There is no such restriction on C.

How many n lettered 'hokage' words are possible?

My attempt:
I noted that the word is of form of an alternating form, An example is 'AAAAACCCCBBCCAACACCCBBC'.

That is, when A starts then it must end with C. When B starts, it also similarly ends in C. C can end in any of A or B.

The Case wise approach was pretty difficult (or so i felt).

So I tried using recursion but ended up getting nowhere.

Comment: by "followed", it seems you mean "followed immediately"

Comment: Yes followed immediately...

Comment: Thanks i edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** In order to find a recursion, note the following. There are 3 ways that we can build a valid word of length $n+1$:

1. A, followed by a valid word starting with either A or C of length $n$,
2. B, followed by a valid word starting with either B or C of length $n$,
3. C, followed by any valid word of length $n$.

By symmetry, the number of valid words of length $n$ that begin with A is equal to the number of valid words of length $n$ that begin with B.

---

Some further explanation. Let $a_n$ denote the number of valid words of length $n$ that begin with $A$, and let $c_n$ denote the number of valid words of length $n$ that begin with $C$. From the rules above, we have
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n + c_n\\
c_{n+1} = 2a_n + c_n
$$
and of course, $a_1 = c_1 = 1$. In terms of matrices, we can write
$$
\pmatrix{a_{n+1}\\ c_{n+1}} = \pmatrix{1 & 1\\2 & 1} \pmatrix{a_n\\ c_n}.
$$

Comment: @S I've added some further explanation.

Comment: Ahh, i get it now.... thanks @B